# UnknownError issue with when querying communications/calls/{id}

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I am using the following code to query the Graph API to retrieve a Team's call information. However, I constantly get the error (pasted below). I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
 // The client credentials flow requires that you request the
 // /.default scope, and preconfigure your permissions on the
 // app registration in Azure. An administrator must grant consent
 // to those permissions beforehand.
 string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    
 // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
 // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
 //string tenantId = "common";
 string tenantId = AzureDetails.TenantID;
    
 // Values from app registration
 string clientId = AzureDetails.ClientID;
 string clientSecret = AzureDetails.ClientSecret;
    
 // using Azure.Identity;
 TokenCredentialOptions options = new()
 {
     AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
 };
    
 // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
 ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
    
 GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    
 call = await graphClient.Communications.Calls[id].Request().GetAsync();
```

Exception:

```
 Code: UnknownError
 Inner error:
     AdditionalData:
     date: 2022-08-30T17:11:46
     request-id: b00e1f14-82d7-459b-bbdc-ae13ae04cdb2
     client-request-id: b00e1f14-82d7-459b-bbdc-ae13ae04cdb2
 ClientRequestId: b00e1f14-82d7-459b-bbdc-ae13ae04cdb2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the permission issue, These the are the permissions required for getting the communication call information:

[image]

Only application permissions are supported not delegated permissions for this API.
Please also check your token here https://jwt.ms/, if it has requested permissions.

Comment: The app registration has the required permissions. I can query the communications/callRecords/{id} endpoint using the same app reg, but it does not work for communications/calls/{id} endpoint